# Get action in Push Notification when App in background

Tags: android, notifications

How to get action in Push Notification when App in background?. I am using this functionality in Android Oreo getting some issue when app in background.

Comment: can you pls elaborate more

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Have you googled before asking?

Comment: `NotificationCompat.Buildert` in api 26 needs to pass in the constructor `NotificationChannel` id, may this occurs your issue. But to help you we need more details. Let share a logcat error.

Comment: Yes, I did. I want to solve this issue from app end.

Comment: NotificationCompa.Buildert in api 26 needs to pass in the constructor NotificationChannel id, may this occurs your issue. But to help you we need more details .. this for only show the notification in Oreo and later version

Comment: So, your notification is showing, but on tap it's crashing?

Comment: App is not crashing. when app in background, click on notification then only open the app not open particular screen. 
When app in foreground click on notification then open particular screen.

Comment: 0
down vote
Using this code you can get the notification in background/foreground and also put action:

//Data should come in this format from the notification
{
  "to": "/xyz/Notifications",
  "data": {
      "key1": "title notification",
      "key2": "description notification"
  }
}
In-App use this code:

  @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
      String key1Data = remoteMessage.getData().get("key1");
      // use key1Data to according to your need
    }

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this in background services. I'm tested that in emulator, but not in real device. Check does this will work for you.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = ...;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(you can put extras);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
            0);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

Also, if you'd like to show an activity, when device is locked, put this in your activity onCreate(), this should work. One thing, when this doesn't work, is when a incoming/outgoing call screen is shown

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    setContentView(...);
```